# How to export SVG from a typescript custom package to React Native Project

Tags: typescript, react-native, svg, package, export

I have a custom package called "app-packages", and i want all of my .png and .svg stored in this package. I manage to export the .png files but i have problems exporting and using the .svg file.

I already installed
https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer & https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg in my app-packages and react native app.

What i have tried:

I have src/Arrow.svg in the package, and i export it like this in src/index.tsx.

```
export { default as SvgPicture} from './Arrow.svg'
```

i already create a declaration.d.ts in src/

```
declare module "*.svg" {
    import React from 'react';
    import {
        SvgProps
    } from "react-native-svg";
    const content: React.FC<SvgProps> ;
    export default content;
}
```

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ESNext",
  "module": "ESNext",
  "strict": true,
  "outDir": "build",
  "declaration": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "importHelpers": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "allowJs": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "es2016", "es2017"],
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "isolatedModules": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noUnusedParameters": true,
  "noEmit": true
},
"include": ["src", "src/declaration.d.ts"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
```

}

after all that done, i build the package and tried it in my app.
like this

```
import {SvgPicture} from 'app-packages';
```

and call it like this in render because i already installed react-native-svg-transformer

```
 <SvgPicture />
```

but the result is this

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `../../../Arrow.svg` must be a function (received `undefined`).
```

if the SVG file is in my react native app, the step above will show the .svg. But it will fail if i move it to app-packages. Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: only a work around, i cant export a svg directly. but i can export a string variable. so i copy the svg code and change it to a string. In my react native project,  i import the variable then change it using svg and svg transformer

Comment: I fixed it, but i don't remember how i did.